# Making auto-hidden taskbar visible on window maximize without un-hiding it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to work around this bug in the MFC feature pack: [Windows 7 taskbar won't auto-unhide when wizard-built MFC app is maximized](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585121/windows-7-taskbar-wont-auto-unhide-when-wizard-built-mfc-app-is-maximized).

The problem:

When the app is maximized and the user has auto-hide on their task-bar, the window covers the "hidden" taskbar (which should still be visible but only 1 pixel high). When the hidden task-bar is coved like this the user can not un-hide it by moving their mouse to the bottom of the screen.

To get to the taskbar the user has to press the windows key or Alt-Tab.

What I've tried:

- Testing if the window is maximized on window focus and calling ShowWindow/BringWindowToFront on the taskbar. This makes the taskbar visible but auto opens it as if moving the mouse over it. I would like to just show the task-bar in its "hidden" state (1 pixel high).
- Resizing the window to leave one row of pixels at the bottom of the screen - This doesn't work on a maximized window.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Annoying feature of Windows 7 to run every caption less window in full screen over taskbar 
...
Windows 7 actually accomplishes this by reseting TOPMOST flag. So we need to set it back.
This is also the reason why Taskbar properties no longer have Always on Top checkbox.

```
void CMainFrame::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
  CWnd::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);

  // Windows7 bug fix
  if (nID == SC_MAXIMIZE)
  {
    HWND hTaskbar = ::FindWindowW(L"Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
    ::SetWindowPos(hTaskbar, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Thought, resize of maximized window may work, if you process `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. Patch `ptMaxSize` / `ptMaxPosition` after "DefWindowProc".
2. Did you try `SetWindowPos (hTaskbar, *YourHwnd*, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE)`?